# how to import excel file in mysql database using php?

Tags: php, mysql, excel, image, mysqli

I want to know how to import or upload excel data to my mysql database using php code with primary key is generated using timestamp function of php.
Please help on it.
And also Upload images with same name of primary key value for each product.
Thank you

Comment: Please tell us what have you tried.

Comment: We are not here for your home work?? At-least show some effort.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
**example for import excel or csv file to mysql database with very easy method.
query:**

 - CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `studentdata`(   `StudentID` int(11) NOT
   NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   `FirstName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,   `LastName`
   varchar(30) NOT NULL,   `MobileNo` varchar(30) NOT NULL,  `City`
   varchar(30) NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`StudentID`) ) E

NGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if($_FILES['csvFile']['name']!="")
    {   $fileName=uploadFile($_FILES['excelFile'],array(".csv"),"excel_file");
        $row=0;
        if(($handle = fopen("excel/".$fileName , "r")) !== FALSE) 
        {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
            {
                $num = count($data);
                $query="INSERT INTO StudentData(FirstName,LastName,MobileNo,City)
                                VALUES('".$data[0]."','".$data[1]."','".$data[2]."','".$data[3]."')";
                mysql_query($query);
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }
    }
    else if($_FILES['excelFile']['name']!="")
    {
        $fileName=uploadFile($_FILES['excelFile'],array(".xls",".xlsx"),"excel_file");
        $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
        $data->read('excel_file/'.$fileName);
        for($i=1;$i<=$data->sheets[0]['numRows'];$i++)
        {
            $firstname=$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][1];
            $lastname=$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][2];
            $mobile=$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][3];
            $city=$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][4];
            $query="INSERT INTO StudentData(FirstName,LastName,MobileNo,City)
                        VALUES('".$firstname."','".$lastname."','".$mobile."','".$city."')";
            mysql_query($query);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your effort is appreciated. But its not a tutorial site. Welcome to stack

Comment: This is a code-dump with no explanation and it requires a 3rd party library, with no explanation for setting it up or using it.

Answer (score -1):

Make two files: index.php (for displaying form for upload) and import.php (for importing data to mysql database). Also Included NOW() for timestamp..
Code for Index.php :

```
<?php
$uploadedStatus = 0;
if ( isset($_POST["submit"]) ) {
if ( isset($_FILES["file"])) {
//if there was an error uploading the file
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
}
else {
if (file_exists($_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
unlink($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
}
$storagename = "file1.xlsx";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],  $storagename);
$uploadedStatus = 1;
}
} else {
echo "No file selected <br />";
}
}


<table width="600" style="margin:115px auto; background:#f8f8f8; border:1px solid #eee; padding:20px 0 25px 0;">
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<tr><td colspan="2" style="font:bold 21px arial; text-align:center; border-bottom:1px solid #eee; padding:5px 0 10px 0;">
<a href="http://www.website.com" target="_blank">website.com</a></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" style="font:bold 15px arial; text-align:center; padding:0 0 5px 0;">Browse and Upload Your File </td></tr>
<tr>
<td width="50%" style="font:bold 12px tahoma, arial, sans-serif; text-align:right; border-bottom:1px solid #eee; padding:5px 10px 5px 0px; border-right:1px solid #eee;">Select file</td>
<td width="50%" style="border-bottom:1px solid #eee; padding:5px;"><input type="file" name="file" id="file" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font:bold 12px tahoma, arial, sans-serif; text-align:right; padding:5px 10px 5px 0px; border-right:1px solid #eee;">Submit</td>
<td width="50%" style=" padding:5px;"><input type="submit" name="submit" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
?>

<?php
/************************ YOUR DATABASE CONNECTION START HERE   ****************************/

define ("DB_HOST", "localhost"); // set database host
define ("DB_USER", ""); // set database user
define ("DB_PASS",""); // set database password
define ("DB_NAME",""); // set database name

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Couldn't make connection.");
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link) or die("Couldn't select database");

$databasetable = "YOUR_TABLE";

/************************ YOUR DATABASE CONNECTION END HERE  ****************************/


set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'Classes/');
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

// This is the file path to be uploaded.
$inputFileName = 'file1.xlsx';

try {
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
}

$allDataInSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
$arrayCount = count($allDataInSheet);  // Here get total count of row in that Excel sheet

for($i=2;$i<=$arrayCount;$i++){
$userName = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["A"]);
$userMobile = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["B"]);

$query = "SELECT name FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE name = '".$userName."' and email = '".$userMobile."'";
$sql = mysql_query($query);
$recResult = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$existName = $recResult["name"];
if($existName=="") {
$insertTable= mysql_query("insert into YOUR_TABLE (name, email, addedon) values('".$userName."', '".$userMobile."', '".now()."');");

$msg = 'Record has been added. <div style="Padding:20px 0 0 0;"><a href="http://website.com/uploaded.htm" target="_blank">Go Back to mainpage</a></div>';
} else {
$msg = 'Record already exist. <div style="Padding:20px 0 0 0;"><a href="http://website.com/already.htm" target="_blank">Go Back to tutorial</a></div>';
}
}
echo "<div style='font: bold 18px arial,verdana;padding: 45px 0 0 500px;'>".$msg."</div>";

?>
```

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions. They're deprecated and evil.